# "Read CSV" file missing in UiPath Studio

Tags: csv, uipath, rpa

I'm wondering where do I find the Read CSV file option in my UiPath Studio.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIWpa.jpg)

Can someone please guide me where do I find that option ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you must not have added the **UiPath.Excel.Activities**

Go to your **Manage Packages** Package and Install the  **UiPath.Excel.Activities**

I'm attaching the screenshot for your reference

[image]